# Is there a way to specifiy an OR operator in an 'if' statement C#?

Tags: c#

Are there *OR* operators in C# which I can use in an *if* statement?

Like for example,

```
if (UserInput == "y" OR "Y")
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Yes: https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/hrsq0l/c_9_new_and_or_and_not_keywords_for_pattern/

Comment: BTW, in your particular case you should use `"Y".Equals( UserInput, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase )` instead.

Comment: [Logical Patterns (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#logical-patterns)

Comment: @Dai this syntax is so counter intuitiv.

Comment: @MaxPowers It isn't counter-intuitive to me :)

Answer (score 4):

C# 9.0 (.NET 5.0+) introduces the **disjunctive `or`** and **conjunctive `and`**  operators which you can use like so:

```
if( UserInput is "y" or "Y" )
```

This is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#pattern-matching-enhancements

They're used in a C# *pattern-matching expression*, which is effectively anywhere.

<sub>As an editorial: be careful though, because the semantics of these new *inclusive* disjunctive and conjunctive operators is in contrast to the *exclusive disjunctive* behaviour of the logical-OR `||` and logical-AND `&&` operators - (and personally while I do see uses for them in for a more succinct *literal set membership* test like SQL's `x IN ( a, b, c )` I'm more worried about people using them inappropriately...</sub>

Answer (score 2):

In the latest [C# versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#pattern-matching-enhancements) you can use pattern matching:

> C# 9 includes new pattern matching improvements:
>
> - ...
> - Conjunctive `and` patterns require both patterns to match
> - Disjunctive `or` patterns require either pattern to match
> - Negated `not` patterns require that a pattern doesn't match
> - ...

```
if (UserInput is "y" or "Y")
{  
    // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative option is to use the `Contains` method and create an extension method.

```
public static bool IsIn(this string source, params string[] values)
{
    return values.Contains(source);
}

bool isAnyY = UserInput.IsIn("Y", "y");
```

Comment: Note that using `params T[]` will incur non-trivial runtime GC heap array allocations.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have 3 options.

```
if (UserInput is "y" or "Y")
{
    // do stuff
}

if (UserInput is "y" || "Y")
{
    // do stuff
}

string UserInput = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
if (UserInput is "y")
{
   // do stuff
}
```